# Function has partial derivatives everywhere, and the partial derivatives are differentiable everywhere, yet function is not differentiable at origin?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I think I don't understand this theorem:

> Let $f$ be defined in a neighbourhood around $a \in \mathbb{R}^p$. If the partial derivatives exist in a neigihbourhood around of $a$ and they are continuous at $a$, then $f$ is differentiable at $a$

The offending function that I would like to evaluate it's differentiability at the origin:

$$
f(x,y) = \frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2}
$$

- $f(t,0)=0$, so the partial derivative $D_xf(t,0) = 0$.
- $f(t,a)=\frac{t^2a}{t^2+a^2}$, the partial derivative exists $\forall a \neq 0$, since this is a rational function.
- $f(0,t)=0$, so the partial derivative $D_yf(0,t) = 0$.
- $f(a,t)=\frac{a^2t}{a^2+t^2}$, the partial derivative exists $\forall a \neq 0$, since this is a rational function.

Thus, the partial derivative exists everywhere. Moreover, the partial derivatives are differentiable everywhere, *so they should be continuous everywhere too, right?*

We can also show that this function is continuous at the origin. HOWEVER, by using the definition of differentiability of a function at the origin,

$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{x^2y - 0 - 0}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)\cdot \sqrt{x^2+y^2}},
$$

if we approach the origin along the line $y=0$, the limit is 0. If we approach the origin along the line $y=x$, then we have that:

$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{x^3}{2x^2\cdot \sqrt{2x^2}} = \pm \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}},
$$

depending from the left or the right. What is going on here. Obviously I misunderstood something about the theorem, but what?

**Edit**:

I'll put in some more calculations in here.

1. Continuity of $f$ at $(0,0)$: if $|(x,y)|< \varepsilon, |\frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2}|=\frac{|x^2||y|}{|x^2+y^2|} \leq \frac{|(x,y)|^2 \cdot |(x,y)|}{|(x,y)|^2} = \varepsilon$. No issues here.
2. $D_xf(x) = \frac{2xy(x^2+y^2)-x^2y\cdot 2x}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2}=\frac{2xy^3}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2}$. As $y\to 0$ this thing is 0, we are good here. Moreoever, fix $y=a\neq 0$, and we have a rational function that is defined everywhere. As a property of rational functions, $D_xf(x)$ is differentiable everywhere and thus continuous everywhere.
3. $D_yf(y)=\frac{x^2(x^2+y^2) - x^2y\cdot 2y}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2}=\frac{x^4 - x^2y^2}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2}$. As $x \to 0$ the limit is $0$, so we are also good here. Same argument like previously, this thing is defined everywhere, and also a rational function  thus differentiable and continuous everywhere.

Comment: I don't think that you checked the continuity of the partial derivatives at the origin correctly. First, you compute the partial derivatives, then you check the continuity at the origin (i.e. all the limits at the origin should agree with $D_{x_i} f(0,0)$.

Comment: @MansurShakipov I attached some calculations on the bottom

Comment: @MansurShakipov but also, before the edit I just used the definition of partial derivatives, applied to the point $(0,0)$. $\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{f(t,0)-f(0,0)}{t}$, which is 0.

Comment: Note that partial derivatives are still functions of both $x$ and $y$, so you can take the limit along different paths. Try doing that for $D_x f(x,y)$ along $x=y$ and $x=-y$ and you will see that $D_xf(x,y)$ is not continuous at the origin.

Comment: @MansurShakipov haaaa... would never have thought the catch is there. My book specifically defines partial derivative as a single variable function.

Comment: Also note that you cannot conclude that the function is **not** differentiable at the origin from the theorem you stated above.

Comment: I wonder if you read the definition of partial derivative correctly. We may **use** a single-variable function while computing a partial derivative at a specific location $(x,y),$ but this is still taking a pair of numbers $(x,y)$ in order to decide the value of one number. The notation you use, $D_x f(x),$ seems incorrect; does your book really write that rather than $D_x f(x,y)$?

Comment: @DavidK I checked, I mis-read. It did define partial derivatives as $D_{x_i}f(a), a\in \mathbb{R}^p$. Moreover, apparently we have that $D_xf(x,b)$ is differentiable everywhere for all $b$. However this is only along(on?) said slice/section. Differentiability of the partial derivative along a section says nothing about continuity of the partial derivative at a point (we can always rotate the slicing plane around the point). I guess I learn something new everyday.

Comment: I think your understanding is good now.

Answer (score 1):

partial derivative with respect to x,

$$f_x=\frac{(x^2+y^2)(2xy)- x^2y(2x)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$$

$$f_x= \frac{(2xy^3)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$$

Let, $$x=rcost, y=rsint$$

$$f_x=\lim_ {r\rightarrow0}\frac { (2r^4cost(sint)^3}{(r^4)}=2costsin^3t$$

Limit depends on value of t ,hence it is not unique .
So, partial derivative is not continious.